# how can I check a variable for a whole number value in php

Tags: php

If I was checking a variable to see if it was a whole number in bash the coding would be similar to

```
if ! [[ "$yournumber" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
```

Is there a way in php to check if the variable contains a whole number?

Thank you all I guess I need to clarify that I want to evaluate that the number does not have a decimal value example is nuber 1  vs  1.2 or any other value with a decimal after it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`ctype_digit`](http://us.php.net/ctype_digit) will probably be faster than regexps.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) for this:

```
if (ctype_digit($yournum)) {
    // ...
}
```

> PHP Docs:
>
> Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are numerical.

This does not include `.`, as shown in their examples (on the page I linked).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same way: `if( preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/",$yournumber))`

Alternatively, try this: `if( strval(intval($yournumber)) === strval($yournumber))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`is_int()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) to check if a variable contains an integer (whole number)

Comment: Asked for whole number values. So `is_int(1.23);` would validate as valid.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `is_numeric()`, really depends on what you want to do actually.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Usually, when your problem is solved, you have to press the gray/green checkmark at the left of the post that helped you solve your problem.

Comment: This is not the answer. As the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) state; "Finds whether the given variable is numeric. Numeric strings consist of optional sign, **any number of digits**, optional decimal part and optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value. Hexadecimal (e.g. 0xf4c3b00c) and binary (e.g. 0b10100111001) notation is not allowed." If you want to find whole numbers you'll need [ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php).

Answer (score 0):

For natural numbers (non-negative whole numbers) use `ctype_digit` as other have suggested.
For whole numbers including negatives you can use this pattern: `/\-?\d+/`.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
is_int($var)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Comment: this will return false if $var is a string: is_int("23") === false